# Pass an annotation argument from properties file?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I am using Hibernate Columntrasnformer annotation to pass execute certain SQL functions while reading from and writing to a column.However one of the arguments of this SQL function is a string that needs to be passed from the properties file.

```
This works
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class myEntity {
    public static final String parameter = "TESTPARAMTER";
    @ColumnTransformer(read = "MY_FUNCTION_READ(my_column_name,"+ parameter "+)", write = "MY_FUNCTION_READ(my_column_name, "+paramter+)"
    @Column(name = "my_column_name")
    private String myColumnName;
}
```

I have moved the variable to a different class and this works too

```
public class Constants{
    public static final String PARAMTER = "TESTPARAMTER";

}

 public class myEntity {
        @ColumnTransformer(read = "MY_FUNCTION_READ(my_column_name,"+ Constants.PARAMETER "+)", write = "MY_FUNCTION_READ(my_column_name, "+ Constants.PARAMETER +)"
        @Column(name = "my_column_name")
        private String myColumnName;
    }
```

However if I change the Constants class to this, it does not work

```
public class Constants{
    @Value("${parameter}")
    public static String PARAMTER;
}
```

I get the error 
***The value for annotation attribute ColumnTransformer.read must be a constant expression***

Is there a way this could be achieved as I have different parameters for different entities. Also the parameters will keep changing. So it will be a huge code maintenance every time a parameter changes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "must be a constant expression" means "must be completely known at compile time". This means approach that you trying to implement will not work, because value from properties file can't be known at compile time.